# Add A Taxonomy Attribute In A Wordpress Shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress plugin created to manage and show event' timetable and schedule.

You can add Event Slots ( post type called 'tcode_event' ) and assign to some specific Event Days ( post type called 'tcode_event-day' )

Then you can show the event timetable with a shortcode [2code-schedule-draw]

I am trying to add the possibility to use custom taxonomies in the plugin in order to make possible create differents schedule with differents Slots and different Days.

For example my aim could be

```
 [2code-schedule-draw pacchetto="tax-slug"]
```

To show only the days and event slots marked with the taxonomy.

I use ACF ( Advanced Custom Field ) to create my custom field in the tcode_event and tcode_event-day to set stuff like location, speaker etc

I added the custom taxonomy in the custom post type, and it works great.

```
// Setup 'pacchetti' taxonomy
add_action('init', function() {
$labels = array(
    'name'              => _x( 'Pacchetti', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name'     => _x( 'Pacchetto', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items'      => __( 'Search Pacchetti' ),
    'all_items'         => __( 'All Pacchetti' ),
    'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Pacchetti' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Pacchetti:' ),
    'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Pacchetti' ),
    'update_item'       => __( 'Update Pacchetti' ),
    'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Pacchetto' ),
    'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Pacchetti Name' ),
    'menu_name'         => __( 'Pacchetti' ),
);
$args = array(
    'hierarchical'      => true,
    'labels'            => $labels,
    'public'            => false,
    'show_ui'           => true,
    'show_admin_column' => false,
    'show_in_quick_edit'=> false,
    'show_tagcloud'     => false,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
    'query_var'         => true,
    'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'pacchetti' ),
);

register_taxonomy('pacchetti', array('tcode_event','tcode_event-day'), $args); });
```

Now i can create and assign my custom taxonomy to the items in my custom post type.

Now i'am stucked on how to add a filter in my shortcode function, i tried several times but it doesn't work.
Here the original shortcode function:

```
// Initialize schedule shortcode 
add_shortcode('2code-schedule-draw', function() {
if (!class_exists('acf')) {
    return 'Could not find ACF. Please make sure it\'s installed or the 
\'Use embedded ACF\' option is selected in event-schedule settings.';
}

$postArray = array();

$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'tcode_event',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => false
));

if (!empty($posts)) {
    foreach($posts as $post) {
        setup_postdata($post);
// field_56b8f1ecb7820 is the key of the array to link the slot to the day
        if (have_rows('field_56b8f1ecb7820', $post->ID)) {
            while (have_rows('field_56b8f1ecb7820', $post->ID)) {
                the_row();

                $datePost = get_sub_field('event_date');

                if (!$datePost || $datePost->post_status !== 'publish') {
                    continue;
                }

                $time = get_sub_field('event_time');
                $time_ends = get_sub_field('event_time_ends');
                $time_end = date('Y-m-d ') . get_sub_field('event_time_end');
                $location = get_sub_field('event_location');
                $date = get_field('event_day_date', $datePost->ID);
                $date = str_replace('/', '-', $date);
                $date = new DateTime($date);
                $dateFormatted = $date->format('Y-m-d');

                $events = isset($postArray[$dateFormatted]) && isset($postArray[$dateFormatted]['events']) ? $postArray[$dateFormatted]['events'] : array();
                $events[] = array(
                    'time' => $time,
                    'time_ends' => $time_ends,
                    'time_end' => $time_end,
                    'event' => $post,
                    'location' => !empty($location) ? $location->slug : ''
                );

                usort($events, function($a, $b) {
                    $aTime = new DateTime($a['time']);
                    $bTime = new DateTime($b['time']);
                    return $aTime->getTimestamp() > $bTime->getTimestamp();
                });

                $locations = isset($postArray[$dateFormatted]) && isset($postArray[$dateFormatted]['locations']) ? $postArray[$dateFormatted]['locations'] : array();

                if (!empty($location)) {
                    $locationsSanitized = array_map(function($cat) {
                        return $cat->slug;
                    }, $locations);

                    if (!in_array($location->slug, $locationsSanitized)) {
                        $locations[] = $location;
                    }
                }

                usort($locations, function($a, $b) {
                    $aName = $a->name;
                    $bName = $b->name;

                    if (isset($a->term_order) && isset($b->term_order)) {
                        $aOrder = $a->term_order;
                        $bOrder = $b->term_order;

                        if ($aOrder !== $bOrder) {
                            return $aOrder < $bOrder;
                        }
                    }

                    return $aName < $bName;
                });

                $postArray[$dateFormatted] = array(
                    'day' => $datePost,
                    'events' => $events,
                    'locations' => $locations
                );
            }
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}

ksort($postArray);
$postArray = array_values($postArray);

$imageFormat = get_field('2code_image_format', 'options');
$daysNum = get_field('2code_number_of_days', 'options');

ob_start();
require TCODE_ES_DIR . '/assets/templates/template.php';
return ob_get_clean();
});
```

Any idea on how to implement my custom taxonomy 'pacchetto' on the shortcode and make it works like a filter?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow shortcode atts, please see the amended below code, note that I added a fallback to posts if pacchetto is not specified in order to display something for the returned loop. Change this to whatever you wish, or set a default value for pacchetto that is used if not populated in the shortcode:

```
function code_schedule_draw($atts) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        "pacchetto" => ''
    ), $atts));

    if (!class_exists('acf')) {
        return 'Could not find ACF. Please make sure it\'s installed or the 
        \'Use embedded ACF\' option is selected in event-schedule settings.';
    }

    $postArray = array();

    if(empty($pacchetto)) {
        $pacchetto = 'posts'
    }

    $posts = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => $pacchetto,
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'suppress_filters' => false
    ));

    if (!empty($posts)) {
        foreach($posts as $post) {
            setup_postdata($post);
            if (have_rows('field_56b8f1ecb7820', $post->ID)) {
                while (have_rows('field_56b8f1ecb7820', $post->ID)) {
                    the_row();

                    $datePost = get_sub_field('event_date');

                    if (!$datePost || $datePost->post_status !== 'publish') {
                        continue;
                    }

                    $time = get_sub_field('event_time');
                    $time_ends = get_sub_field('event_time_ends');
                    $time_end = date('Y-m-d ') . get_sub_field('event_time_end');
                    $location = get_sub_field('event_location');
                    $date = get_field('event_day_date', $datePost->ID);
                    $date = str_replace('/', '-', $date);
                    $date = new DateTime($date);
                    $dateFormatted = $date->format('Y-m-d');

                    $events = isset($postArray[$dateFormatted]) && isset($postArray[$dateFormatted]['events']) ? $postArray[$dateFormatted]['events'] : array();
                    $events[] = array(
                        'time' => $time,
                        'time_ends' => $time_ends,
                        'time_end' => $time_end,
                        'event' => $post,
                        'location' => !empty($location) ? $location->slug : ''
                    );

                    usort($events, function($a, $b) {
                        $aTime = new DateTime($a['time']);
                        $bTime = new DateTime($b['time']);
                        return $aTime->getTimestamp() > $bTime->getTimestamp();
                    });

                    $locations = isset($postArray[$dateFormatted]) && isset($postArray[$dateFormatted]['locations']) ? $postArray[$dateFormatted]['locations'] : array();

                    if (!empty($location)) {
                        $locationsSanitized = array_map(function($cat) {
                            return $cat->slug;
                        }, $locations);

                        if (!in_array($location->slug, $locationsSanitized)) {
                            $locations[] = $location;
                        }
                    }

                    usort($locations, function($a, $b) {
                        $aName = $a->name;
                        $bName = $b->name;

                        if (isset($a->term_order) && isset($b->term_order)) {
                            $aOrder = $a->term_order;
                            $bOrder = $b->term_order;

                            if ($aOrder !== $bOrder) {
                                return $aOrder < $bOrder;
                            }
                        }

                        return $aName < $bName;
                    });

                    $postArray[$dateFormatted] = array(
                        'day' => $datePost,
                        'events' => $events,
                        'locations' => $locations
                    );
                }
            }
        } wp_reset_postdata();
    }

    ksort($postArray);
    $postArray = array_values($postArray);

    $imageFormat = get_field('2code_image_format', 'options');
    $daysNum = get_field('2code_number_of_days', 'options');

    ob_start();
    require TCODE_ES_DIR . '/assets/templates/template.php';
    return ob_get_clean();

} add_shortcode("code-schedule-draw", "code_schedule_draw");
```